# Why is the group method allowed on re.match even though it can sometimes return None?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In following code we are not sure what comes as input to the `match` method (`p.match`), so the result could be `None`, for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
>>> p.match("").group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So is it fine to directly apply the `group` method on the return from the `match` method? Why is Python allowing this, even though `p.match` could `return None`?

Comment: give this question a better title.  what are you actually asking?

Comment: sorry for the confusion created, now the question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for `re.match` returning `None` in the case where there isn't a match is that it makes the following work correctly:

```
if re.match(pattern, string):
    # do whatever with the string
```

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) puts it:

> Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

The `match` object will always evaluate truth-y in a boolean context, whereas `None` evaluates false-y.

The reason Python doesn't prevent you from writing `re.match(...).group(...)` is that, until the code actually runs, it is difficult to tell what `re.match(...)` could return: you may have redefined `re` or monkey-patched `match`; the arguments aren't known ahead of time; etc.. This is because Python is a very dynamic language, in terms of typing and introspection.

You therefore have two options, either [look before you leap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-lbyl):

```
match = re.match(...)
if match:
    match.group(...)
```

or [ask forgiveness rather than permission](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
try:
    re.match(...).group(...)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Could you please give any link to understand about truth-y and false-y also

Comment: @RajeshKumar start with https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing, and play with https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool

Answer (score 2):

You're failing to understand how Python works. It **can't** know that the object doesn't have a method of that name until the object actually *exists*. So the fix is to make sure you don't try to call that method if you don't get the object you expect.

Comment: Agreed, but in fairness it wouldn't be unreasonable to have returned a match object with a .group() method that returns None. Of course, then you would have punted the check for None one level deeper without getting rid of it. I wonder if re.match might throw something like a MatchNotFoundException if it were written today?

Comment: It's not really an exception per se, it's "no match found".

Comment: For comparison, str.index raises a ValueError when the substring isn't found. Note than I'm thinking out loud, not complaining. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex won't match the input empty string, since `[a-z]+` matches one or more lowercase alphabets.

Because there isn't a match occurs, it shows the error like above.

```
>>> p = re.compile('[a-z]*')
>>> p.match("").group()
''
```

This shows a match because `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.